# Given the address of an object, how would I call Obj-C methods on it in an LLDB Python script?

Tags: python, objective-c, lldb

In pseudo-code, I'd like to create a reusable LLDB Python script that works like this:

```
get_super_class(int address) {
    return ((id)address).getSuperClass();
}
```

Called like this:

```
(lldb) get_super_class(0x123abc)
UIViewController
```

Any ideas? I'm a python novice. I would think there is something in the documentation for [SBValue](http://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/lldb.SBValue-class.html) that would get me close to what I want, but I don't see it if there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not at my computer (actually at a restaurant in Reno :) so what follows is mostly cursory but it should point you in the right direction

What you want to do is compose the expression as a string. Say you are looking to do foo(X) where foo is defined as

id foo(id arg)

What you can do is make yourself a string

"(id)foo((id)0xaddr"

Then you want to evaluate that as an expression.

I believe either SBTarget or SBFrame have an
EvaluateExpression method
To that you pass your dutifully crafted string, and remember to enable dynamic types since you are dealing with ObjC and most likely want them to be resolved.

What that API will return is yet another SBValue. That you can query for value, summary, description, or you can fetch its children value etc etc..

Hope this helps. If you need more details feel free to ask and I will try and fill in the gaps as I get a chance!

Comment: That's it! The line I used was this: `debugger.GetSelectedTarget().GetProcess().GetSelectedThread().GetFrameAtIndex(0).EvaluateExpression('((id)0x8b464a0)')` Which returns a valid SBValue object for whatever address you pass in.

Comment: Note, for an expression that has no frame-specific information you can use SBTarget::EvaluateExpression() instead of the frame-specific one.  It doesn't make much difference, except that evaluating it in the context of a frame will pin the SBValue's lifecycle to that thread and frame, which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use `SBValue` for that, but you can use `SBCommandInterpreter` to run a command with lldb and capture it's output:

```
# First, get the command interpreter:
ci = lldb.debugger.GetCommandInterpreter()
# Then create an `SBCommandReturnObject` to capture the output
output = lldb.SBCommandReturnObject()
# run an lldb command to get the superclass
ci.HandleCommand("po [" + address + " superclass]", output)
# get the output and strip the trailing line break
superclass = output.GetOutput().rstrip()
```

There might be an easier way (one would hope), but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Pretty good answer, but not quite what I need. My example of returning the superclass was a simplification, which is why I'd prefer to have the actual object instead of calling out to the LLDB command line. I can probably make something similar to your answer work, but it would end up being hacktacular.