# Reading N bytes from a memory address using LLDB's Python API

Tags: python, lldb

Although LLDB's Python API seems incredibly powerful, it's a bit hard to get started. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to read N bytes from a given memory address. I thought I would be able to do so using `lldb.SBValue.CreateValueFromAddress` method, which maps to:

`SBValue_CreateValueFromAddress(SBValue self, char const * name, lldb::addr_t address, SBType type) -> SBValue`

Unfortunately, I can't figure out from the reference documentation what arguments to pass and what they mean. Another approach was to create an `lldb.SBAddress` but again, I get stuck at the same point as the arguments required for `__init__` are unclear to me.

**Question:** How can I read N bytes from a given memory address using LLDB's Python API? Good reading material on the subject is most welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need `lldb.process.ReadMemory`, which I can't find documentation for anywhere. :/

Comment: "it's a bit hard to get started" +1.  But once you get started, the APIs are incredble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`SBProcess.ReadMemory`](https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/lldb.SBProcess-class.html#ReadMemory).

```
def my_command(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    my_address = 0xdeadbeef  # change for some real address
    my_data_size = 0x1000  # change for some real memory size

    error_ref = lldb.SBError()
    process = debugger.GetSelectedTarget().GetProcess()
    memory = process.ReadMemory(my_address, my_data_size, error_ref)
    if error_ref.Success():
        # `memory` is a regular byte string
    else:
        result.AppendString(str(error_ref))
```

`ReadMemory` modifies `error_ref` if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Using `EvaluateExpression` on the current Frame object does the trick. For example:

`debugger.GetSelectedTarget().GetProcess().GetSelectedThread().GetFrameAtIndex(0).EvaluateExpression(*(int*)(0x0000000100400000)).GetValue()`

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275139/given-the-address-of-an-object-how-would-i-call-obj-c-methods-on-it-in-an-lldb?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from Rust's LLDB formatters:

> ```
>     element_type_size = element_type.GetByteSize()
>     def render_element(i):
>         address = start_address + i * element_type_size
>         element_val = raw_value.CreateValueFromAddress(array_name + ("[%s]" % i),
>                                                    address,
>                                                    element_type)
> ```

This is indexing into a contiguous array of memory all of the same type. The name param seems to be a label the debugger can use to display to the user, but is unrelated to the actual value being displayed (I.e. you can set it to anything and it should work).

Alas I haven't quite figured out how one creates the final argument from scratch.